# sharepoint online not showing in office 365 E3 trial plan

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created Office 365 Trial Account but after account creation, it shows only admin center in app launcher and not showing SharePoint online and other option.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will take sometime to create the set up for the SharePoint Admin Center.

[image]

Try to register  for the Below Program, so that we can get one year subscription.

[Join the Microsoft Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram)

Get virtual and in-person learning opportunities, benefits to help you become more innovative and successful, and access to connect with other developers.

1. One-year, FREE Office 365 developer subscription
2. Access to online training's
3. In-person office hours with Microsoft engineers
4. Chances to win tickets to Microsoft conferences and industry events
5. Opportunities to participate in virtual hackathons to build modern
   productivity solutions with Office
6. Opportunities to meet with other developers in your area
7. Previews of and insights into Office Extensibility announcements

Comment: I have joined the developer program and created a trial account in the morning however still it doest not have a SharePoint option in admin centre.

Comment: Please go to main admin  center  and you will find the separate  admin center for sharepoint  as shown  in image

Comment: please find the attached screenshot